# How to perform logic after ItemWriter has completed?

Tags: spring-batch

Hi all I'm new to SO and to Springbatch. I have written a batch job with Classifer that updates a table in two different ways (i.e. two ItemWriters) depending on what's retrieved through the ItemReader and all that's working fine. Now, I want to perform some logic after the ItemWriters are done updating. I want to do some logging and update another table with the same set of data retrieved previously. How can I achieve this? I looked at ItemWriterListener but seems it cannot perform data specific logics. I did some searching but with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you need that logic for each chunk, or can you define a tasklet after that step? Why can't you use a [ChunkListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ChunkListener.html)?

Comment: Look at ItemWriter Close method where you can do the operation you want to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, I want to perform some logic after the ItemWriters are done updating. I want to do some logging and update another table with the same set of data retrieved previously. How can I achieve this? I looked at ItemWriterListener but seems it cannot perform data specific logics.

Since you want to do something with the same items retrieved previously, you need to use a [`ItemWriteListener#afterWrite`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html#afterWrite-java.util.List-) as this method gives you access to the items that have just been written.

**EDIT**: Add details about the failure case based on comments

If the transaction is rolled back, the method `ItemWriteListener#onWriteError` will be called. Please find more details about this in the [common patterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#loggingItemProcessingAndFailures) section.

Comment: Thank! I think this is what I'm looking for, except it seems to be called before commit. If by any chance the commit fail, will it still execute?

Comment: No, it is another method `#onWriteError` that will be called. I edited the question with more details. Please accept it if it helped.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine suppose if spring batch chunk size is 100 but my reader query is 500 so spring batch runs 5 times . ItemWriteListener#afterWrite will be called 5 times after every chunk run or only once?

Comment: @SanjayNaik `ItemWriteListener#afterWrite` is called after every chunk, so in that case it will be called 5 times since you have 5 chunks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using StepExecutionListener implementing it to your Writer Class to execute logic once ItemWriter is done with the execution. Below is a snippet of the ItemWriter for your reference,

```
public class TestWriter implements ItemWriter<Test>, StepExecutionListener {

   @Override
   public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

   }

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends Test> items) throws Exception {
        // Logic of Writer
   }


   @Override
   public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

       // You can perform post logic after writer here inside afterStep based on your requirements

       // Return custom exit status based on the run

       return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
   }
}
```